# Does Legacy Objective C code with MVC pattern co-exist with RxSwift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, rx-swift

We have an application that has huge code base written in Objective C following MVC pattern.
Now we are planning to use RxSwift(with MVVM pattern) for adding new features/screens to the existing app. Is this recommended approach to do this? How good is the interoperability between these two?

Also we are thinking of migrating the entire code base in a phased manner to RxSwift. I am new to RxSwift. I couldn't get any help regarding this if someone else have achieved this without any issue. Just wanted to know what kind of issues we might encounter in this process and what kind of effort is needed here.

Is it possible to call obj c functions in RxSwift and vice versa?

Comment: Have you heard about the new SwiftUI? It basically is RxSwift.

Comment: Yes I did hear about SwiftUI but do not know about it in detail. So with the invent of SwiftUI, do you think RxSwift is no more required? If we get that clear maybe we can drop this idea of converting everything to RxSwift which is anyway new for us.

Comment: I cannot tell you your company strategy. I’m suggesting you watch the WWDC videos and do some thinking. They explain very well how to adopt SwiftUI a little at a time and how it interacts with legacy code.

Comment: SwiftUI is for iOS 13+ only. I expect a legacy app will not be using it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxSwift and MVVM on its own don't specify how transition between screens are governed. The most common approach seem to be using **FlowControllers**. Here's a good [read](http://merowing.info/2016/01/improve-your-ios-architecture-with-flowcontrollers/) to get familiar with the concept.

The important conclusion is **FlowControllers** do work for any screen approach being it either MVC or MVVM / RxSwift . **But** that assumes your MVC screens (i.e. viewControllers and/or storyboards' segues) do not hold dependencies to other screens (through segues or view controller pushing/poping and that kind of stuff). If you would like to mix MVC & MVVM / RxSwift most likely you would need first strip your view controllers from any screen transition logic.

From my experience the critical aspect to keep the building blocks interchangeable is to limit the *reactivity* only to MVVM binding part of the screen. What it effectively means is to keep the **FlowControllers** non reactive to be able to use any approach one chooses for the screens. By doing so later it's much easier to replace RxSwift which some other approach like Apple's `Combine` for example.

On your last question there no serious limits for calling objective-c functionality from Swift, RxSwift is irrelevant. That's not the case vice versa though and pure Swift classes & structs are inaccessible directly from objective-c. But with proper leverage of **FlowControllers** that shouldn't be a big a problem. A potential challenge might be sharing data models / network api etc if you go with pure Swift approach with its new constructs (Codeable and such).